# Reading NHibernate configuration file from C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

In my web application, I am using NHibernate configured by an xml file (nhibernate.cfg.xml). I need to read the connection string from that file in my C# code. My code is working, but I don't like it (in particular the foreach!) and I would like to query the xml file in a straight manner. I have tried to query it with link, but I always get null nodes.
Here is the cfg file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">
      NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
    </property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">
      NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver
    </property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">
      Server=LEG\SQL12;initial catalog=DVR;user id=daniele;pwd=s;
    </property>
    <property name="dialect">
      NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect
    </property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and here it is my C# code:

```
public static String GetConnectionString()
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_connectionString))
    {
        XElement root = XElement.Load("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        var sessionFactoryNode = root.Elements().FirstOrDefault();  // session-factory
        if (sessionFactoryNode != null)
        {
            var properties = sessionFactoryNode.Elements();
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                if (property.Attribute("name").Value == "connection.connection_string")
                    _connectionString = property.Value.Trim();
            }
        }
    }
    return _connectionString;
}
```

How can I obtain the same result querying the xml?

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("hibernate.cfg.xml");
var connString = root.Descendants("property")
             .Where(p => (string) p.Attribute("name") == "connection.connection_string")
             .Select(p => (string) p)
             .First();
```

Comment: I tried this, but root.Descendants("property") give me "Enumeration yielded no results".